# Jekyll-now: table headers are not rendered properly

Tags: css, github, markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I am totally new to markdown/css, and I am trying to set up my blog at Github Pages.

I have problems displaying the table headers correctly.

This is how I create them in my `.md` file, which is coming directly from a notebook generated with Jupyter and R:

```
<table>
<thead><tr><th></th><th scope=col>ID</th><th scope=col>City</th><th scope=col>Province</th><th scope=col>Italians</th><th scope=col>Population</th><th scope=col>Percentage</th><th scope=col>Lat</th><th scope=col>Lon</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
```

and this is how they get visualized by Jekyll-now:
[image]

**What am I doing wrong here?**

**EDIT**

This is the `html` code with which the table headers are rendered:

```
<p><br />City             Province         Italians   Population   % Italians   Lat     Lon&lt;/br&gt;
```

I don't know if that's due to Jekyll using a different markdown engine than Github.

Comment: What does the HTML source look like?

Comment: I don't know as the post itself has been saved as markdown. I figured out this was the preferred way of sharing notebooks. Not that I'm convinced of this...

Comment: Without the raw HTML we can't help much. Screenshots are useless to debug Markdown, Instead of taking a screenshot, right-click and select "view source" (or whatever variation your browser uses). Then edit your question and copy and paste the HTML in.

Comment: Please check my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered this issue today and finally I find a way to make it work. It's quite simple, you only need to add quotation marks after `scope=` like below:

```
<table>
<thead><tr><th></th>
<th scope="col">ID</th>
<th scope="col">City</th>
<th scope="col">Province</th>
<th scope="col">Italians</th>
<th scope="col">Population</th>
<th scope="col">Percentage</th>
<th scope="col">Lat</th>
<th scope="col">Lon</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
```

You can check my post on github pages at https://juntaodong.com/BANA7038-HW1/
and the corresponding raw markdown at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JuntaoDong/juntaodong.github.io/master/_posts/2019-01-23-BANA7038-HW1.md